# Prove $S$ has a least element.

Tags: proof-verification, well-orders

Can anyone help me with my proof, please? I only got half points, but my professor won't tell me what I am doing wrong. My proof is:

> Let $z$ $\in \mathbb{Z}$. If $S$ is a nonempty set of integers that are all greater than or equal to $z$, then $S$ has a least element.

And this is what I have:

First note that $S$ is the nonempty set of integers greater than or equal to $z$. We will create and use the alternative set $Q$, where $Q=\{x\in \mathbb{Z}\mid x=g+(-z), g\in S\}$ for some integer $g$. $Q$ is in the set of whole numbers because all elements of $S$ are greater than $z$ and $g$ is in $S$, so our lowest possible result from this is zero, therefore $Q$ is in the set of whole numbers and know it has a least element because of the least ordering principle and the set of whole numbers non-empty and positive. Since we added -$z$ to $S$ to get to the set of whole numbers, we must add $z$ to get back to the set of integers. Since $g+(-z)$ was the least element in the set $Q$ and we added $z$ to get back to the set $S$, we suspect that $k+z$ is the least element in $S$ for some integer $k \in S$. We must now prove $k+z \in S$, and we will do this by using proof by contradiction. That is, we will assume $k+z$ is less than some integer $r$ in $S$ and show that $k+z$ is not less than or equal to $r$. We begin with $r>k+z$. We begin by subtracting $z$ from both sides to get $r-z>k$. Since both $k$ and $r$ are in $S$, they are greater than or equal to $z$, so $r-z$ would be less than $k$ and we have come to a contradiction of our assumption that $k+z$ is less than some integer $r$ in $S$ which proves $k+z$ is the least element in $S$ and completes the proof.

Comment: I applaud the content, which clearly shows your participation in the learning process.  But large masses of text are generally hard to read.  It will help us help you if you use paragraphs to break up the text, one idea at a time.

Comment: @RobertShore Indeed. Rearranging will also help OP to give a clear account of the structure of the argument - and that will help OP to analyse possible weaknesses. It is good to get into the discipline of writing clear arguments - it is so easy to confuse yourself otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You never picked what the least element was. Let's say you meant for $k$ to be the least element. What you then want to prove is not that $k+z\in S$, which is obvious, but rather that $k+z$ is the least element of $S$. You seem to have attempted to do that, but never succeeded.

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to say with "We will assume $k+z$ is less than some integer $r$ in $S$ and show that $k+z$ is not less than or equal to $r$." But you *want* $k+z$ to be less than or equal to $r$. Perhaps you meant that $k+z$ is less than $r$, but this need not be true as we could take $r=k+z$. Reading before that, you *assume* that $k+z$ is less than $r$ from the outset, which is what you actually want to show.

The way to complete it would be to prove that if $r\in S$, then $k+z\leq r$. To do this, we note that $k\leq r-z$ because $r-z\in Q$ and $k$ is the least element of $Q$, hence $k+z\leq r=(r-z)+z$.

Answer (score 0):

If z is in S then we are done.
If z is not in S, then see if z+1 is in S. If so then z+1 is the least element. Else see if z+2 is in S. If so then it is the least element. Keep adding 1 until you get an element in S.

If you keep adding 1 and never reach an element in S then S is not a nonempty set of integers all >= k, a contradiction.

Therefore, if you keep adding 1 to k, you will, at some point, get to the lowest integer in S.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S=P \cup N$, where $P$ is the set of non-negative elements of $S$ and $N$ is the set of negative elements of $S$.  If $N \neq \emptyset$, then $N$ is finite so it has a least element.  Moreover, every element of $N$ is less than every element of $P$, so the least element of $N$ is necessarily the least element of $S$.

If $N = \emptyset$, then $P \neq \emptyset$.  Since $P$ is a non-empty set of natural numbers, by the well-ordering principle $P$ has a least element, and since $N = \emptyset \Rightarrow P=S$, that means $S$ has a least element.

The problem with your proof is that you have not defined $S$ correctly.  You have defined it as *all* integers $k \geq z$.  That's not correct.  Although all of the elements of $k \in S$ have the property $k \geq z$, as $S$ is defined in the problem, it's not in general true that $S$ contains all such integers.

For example, it's possible that $z=-5$ and $S=\{3, 8\}$.  You're trying to define it as $T= \{ k \in \Bbb Z \mid k \geq z \} = \{-5, -4, -3, \ldots \}$, and while it's true that $S \subset T$ and you have proved the result for $T$, the inclusion can be proper so you haven't yet proved it for all possible $S$.